# @media query code

Tags: css, media-queries

**Can this be done?**

`.col` is the main section.

If I resize from above 1142px to 1141px I want the `.col` to disappear.

If I resize, I can see the `.kaartmw` but the `.col` doesn't disappear.

If I resize from less 1141pxpx to 1142px and above the `.kaartmw` will disappear just like I want to have.

That can't be done with this code.

The question is why?

Note that I have changed the max-width and min-width

```css
/* MEDIA QUERY 1142px*/
@media screen and (min-width:1142px){
    .kaartmw {
        display: none;
    }

/* MEDIA QUERY 1142px*/
@media screen and (max-width:1141px){
    .col {
        display: none;
    }
```

Comment: Live demos are all very well… but they don't demo much if you don't include any HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `}` to close each media query section.

[A validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) is a useful tool for detecting this type of problem.